# Custom unlock item button in sitecore experience editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In Sitecore 8.1 update 2, how do we add a custom web edit button in experience editor to unlock items locked by other users using non admin authors in sitecore.
Getting below error while executing the command.

```
ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ExperienceEditor.CustomUnlockItem error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ExperienceEditor.CustomUnlockItem
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have configured already to help diagnose the issue you are having?

Comment: Sorry it was i config issue ...got resolved thanks

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the config  it was working fine, below is the correct configuration.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>

      <command name="webedit:customlock">
        <patch:attribute name="type"><NameSpace>.CustomLock,<Assembly></patch:attribute>
      </command>

    </commands>

    <sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>

        <request name="ExperienceEditor.CustomUnlockItem" type="<NameSpace>.CustomUnlockItem, <Assembly>" />

        <request name="ExperienceEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl" type="<NameSpace>.GenerateFieldEditorUrl, <Assembly>" />

        </sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>


  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```